# Recursive Python Question - Where is n being updated?

Tags: python

In this very classic recursive example, where is the variable n being updated?

Would you not have to

```
def factorial(n):
    if n <= 1: # BASE CASE
        return 1
    return n * factorial(n - 1) # RECURSIVE CALL
```

Why would you not have to have

```
def factorial(n):
        if n <= 1: # BASE CASE
            return 1
        return n * factorial(n - 1) # RECURSIVE CALL
        n = n - 1 ## why is something like this not needed?
```

Comment: *why is something like this not needed?* Why would it be needed? You aren't going to use `n` again, are you?

Comment: you need to assign n to something like val ie val = n and n=n-1 and then to use recursion using `return val * factorial(n)` need to do in order to avoid all this unnecessary code, just use `return n * factorial(n-1)`

Comment: `n` is a local variable. Updating it would have no effect.

Comment: Imagine if, instead of making a recursive call, this code used the standard library `math.factorial` to compute the sub-result. Would you have the same question? Why not? **Why do you expect that this situation is different**? Calling the function recursively is just like calling any other function. It's just... calling a function. Aside from that: how are you expecting that it would ever have an effect to put code *after an unconditional `return`*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `n` does not have to be updated.  We're making a new call to `factorial` with a reduced value of `n`.  Each call to `factorial` only works with one `n` value.  Consider how this works.

Say we call `factorial(3)`, so `n` is 3.  3 is clearly not less than or equal to 1, so we get down to the return statement.  We're going to multiply something by 3, but we don't know what yet.  We then call `factorial(2)`.

That starts a NEW call to `factorial`, unrelated to the original.  In this call, `n` is still greater than 1, so we get to the `return` statement, and we start multiplying 2 by something.  That something calls `factorial(1)`.

In THIS call to factorial, `n` is less than or equal to 1, so we return 1.

Now we go back out to the second call, where we were in the middle of a multiplication.  That line was basically:

```
    return 2 * factorial(1)
```

which we now know is

```
    return 2 * 1
```

so the second invocation returns 2.  We now back out to the original invocation, where we had

```
    return 3 * factorial(2)
```

factorial(2) returned 2, so this becomes

```
    return 3 * 2
```

which returns 6 to the original caller.

`n` never gets updated.  It's just that each new call to the function gets a reduced value.